# Lp spaces - example of function

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Can you give me an example of function which:
$$f \in L^{p}[a,b]$$ but $$f \not\in L^{\infty}[a,b]$$
$L^{\infty}[a,b]$ is space of essentially bounded function at interval $[a,b]$

$1 \le p < \infty$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What range of $p$?

Comment: $1 \le p < \infty$

Comment: Looks like you have a good answer below...

Answer (score 4):

The function $x\to-\log x$ belongs to $L^p((0,1))$ for any $p\geq 1$ but it is not essentially bounded.

Comment: Is it maybe a problem that OP asks for intervals of the form $[a,b]$ and yours is of the form $(a,b)$?

Comment: @AlfredYerger: The Lebesgue measure is a diffuse measure hence the endpoints do not really matter here.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt(x)} \in L^{1}$ is another good example at $[0,1]$ ?  I think that function $\frac{1}{\sqrt(x)}$ isn't esspentailly bounded